# Signal matching and noise extraction

Tags: python, signals, filtering, signal-processing, fft

I wish to match two signals and then extract a matching signal from one of the signals. Note that one of the signals appears to be more noisy. How can I design a filter to extract the matching components and later on determine the excessive noise.

Comment: Please clarify: you want to match the noise level of the two signals? Or you want to match the signals? In principle you cannot separate signal from noise, the best you can do is estimate the signal from the data, you assume that the noise is the part you discard in that process. Google for “signal noise filtering” or some such. There are lots of different methods out there, what is best depends on the signal and the noise. — Also: you’ll get more attention on SO if you pick a language, implement something, and tag the question with that language.

Comment: I want to match the two signals. Considering, one of the signals appears to be less noisy, I wish to match and extract it from the more noisy signal. The remaining component after the extraction (added noise) is also important to me. I hope it now makes sense. I have added a tag for my preferred programming language, python.

Comment: Are the signal in phase or there is shifting between them? Also, are the signals periodical?

Comment: The signals are periodical and may be slightly out of phase.